# Apache FOP mixed page size

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have a requirement to generate PDFs of procedures written in XML. These procedures have images. Some are foldouts, or 11x17 page size images. How can I create an 11x17 sized page in between two 8.5x11 sized pages? I have been able to create the fold outs at the end of the document using a separate `<fo:page-sequence>`, but they really need to be generated inline within the procedure. Is what I am trying to accomplish possible using FOP, or any other formatter for that matter?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know where in the sequence the pages occur, you could consider a two-pass solution: http://www.CraneSoftwrights.com/resources/#psmi

The end result of the second pass is pure XSL-FO without the use of extensions.

Answer (score 1):

If you know where in the sequence the pages occur, you can use `fo:page-sequence-master` to put a 11x17 page at the right point in the sequence, e.g.:

```
<fo:page-sequnce-master master-reference="psm">
  <fo:repeatable-page-master-reference master-reference="a"
                                       maximum-repeats="8" />
  <fo:single-page-master-reference master-reference="p11x17" />
  <fo:repeatable-page-master-reference master-reference="a"
                                       maximum-repeats="8" />
</fo:page-sequence-master>
```

Antenna House AH Formatter has an extension for nesting `fo:page-sequence` that you could perhaps use for inserting an 11x17 page where it falls.  See https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf63/ahf-ext.html#fo.page-sequence